# Log residual adjustment for model

Tags: python, logging

I tried to predict the Sydney housing price and after I proceed data, I found the price cannot get normalised using log. But I still keep building the boosting model. The question is: 
How to adjust the residual after log? It means that I think log would make residual/error larger.
Thanks

```
# normal distribution of train response value
log=np.log(training_data["price"])
skew = stats.skew(log)
print(skew)
k2, p = stats.normaltest(log)
alpha = 1e-3
print("p = {:g}".format(p))
if p < alpha:  # null hypothesis: x comes from a normal distribution
    print("The null hypothesis can be rejected")
else:
     print("The null hypothesis cannot be rejected")
```

The result is p = 4.07145e-07
The null hypothesis can be rejected